# How to call a nested function from another function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a inner function from another function.I have code like

```
$(document).on('click','.td-subject-button',function(){ 
 var current= $(this).parent('td');     
     function setData(){
        return current;
     }
});

function  addSubjectTeacher(){
    var value=setData();
    console.log(value);
}
```

In the console i am getting the result as '`setData is not defined`'. because the setData function is a nested function of a another function. so, how can i invoke setData function.

Comment: Define setData outside the click callback block

Comment: var value=setData();
function addSubjectTeacher(){console.log(value)}

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/313880). Please explain what your _actual problem_ is and don't get too attached to this _attempted solution_ of calling a scoped function from the global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define your `var current` outside [globally] and get its value as below.

> **Assumption -** You will be calling `addSubjectTeacher` function after `click event` of `td-subject-button`

```
var current = "";
$(document).on('click','.td-subject-button',function(){ 
   current= $(this).parent('td');     
});

function  addSubjectTeacher(){
   var value=current;
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Anytime bro.. Happy coding.. :)